# prestashop - cannot import csv file

Tags: csv, import, prestashop

I am trying to upload a product csv file:

```
56456145614;1;test product;Test;;;440;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;test product;;;;;;;;;;;;http://thedomain.com/imgimport/BASIC%20S:S-AFRICATEE-BK.jpg
```

and I get the error:

```
test product (ID 56456145614) Cannot be saved
```

The Prestashop version I am using: 1.4.8.2.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Need more info in order to help

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy what more info would be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a problem with the first parameter which is the id `56456145614`.

I used a smaller number e.g. `1001` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem must come from the image name. Try changing it to a name with no special character, no capital letter, no space...
For example `basic-africatee-bk.jpg`

Then, if you to simplify your file and reduce the risk of error, you can also remove empty 'columns' from your csv files.

You can change this:
`56456145614;1;test product;Test;;;440;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;5;test product;;;;;;;;;;;;http://habit.mu/imgimport/BASIC%20S:S-AFRICATEE-BK.jpg`

To this:
`56456145614;1;test product;Test;440;1;5;test product;http://habit.mu/imgimport/basic-africatee-bk.jpg`